# Conditional PDF of Dependent RVs

Tags: conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, convolution

So I'm given that $x, y$ are distributed as:

$
P(\alpha) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1 & 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1 \\
    0 & otherwise
  \end{cases}
$

First I needed to calculate $P_{S}(s)$ where $S = X + Y$, which came out to be (using convolution):

$
P_{s}(s) = 
  \begin{cases}
    s & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \\
    2 - s & 1 \lt s \leq 2 \\
    0 & otherwise
  \end{cases}
$

I now need to calculate $P_{X|S}(x|s)$, which is where I'm stuck. I know that $x$ and $s$ are not independent, so I cannot just say that $P(X, S) = P(X)*P(S)$ and calculate the conditional distribution with this, but I can't think of where to go from here.

---

I believe I may have figured out a solution, in case someone needs help with this in the future.

$\begin{align}
P_{X|S}(x|s) & = P(X=k | X+Y=n) \\
& = P(X=k | Y=n-k) \\
& = \frac{P(X=k, Y=n-k)}{P(X+Y=n)} \\
& = \frac{P(X=k) * P(Y=n-k)}{P(X+Y=n)}
\end{align}$

I'm a little unsure about my conclusion below, so please correct me if I'm mistaken:

$
P_{X|S}(x|s) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{s} & 0 \leq s \leq 1, 0 \leq x \leq s \\
  \frac{1}{2-s} & 1 \lt s \leq 2, s-1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
  0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
$

Comment: Hint: given than $S=a$ where $0 \leq a \leq 1$, can you figure out why it must be that subject to this condition, $X$ must be in $[0, a]$?  What if $a \in (1,2]$? What can be said about $X$ in this case?

Comment: So, would it be something like this?

$
P_{X|S}(x|s) = 
  \begin{cases}
    s & 0 \leq s \leq 1 \\
    2 - s & 1 \lt s \leq 2 \\
    0 & otherwise
  \end{cases}
$

Comment: I think that if you were to plot $S$ on the horizontal and $X$ on the vertical, the distribution would be 1 in a parallelogram with vertices at {(0,0), (0,1), (2,1), (1,0)}. Am I thinking about this correctly? @DilipSarwate

Comment: The _argument_ of $P_{X\mid S}(x\mid s)$ is $x$, not $s$; $s$ is just a fixed number in $[0,2]$, that is, your displayed multiline equation is ass wrong. $P_{X\mid S}(x\mid s)$ can be nonzero only if $x$ in $[0,1]$ regardless of choice of $s$, but it does not have to be nonzero for _all_ $x \in [0,1]$. For example, if $S=0.4$, then $X$ can take on values only in $[0,0.4]$ and so $P_{X\mid S}(x\mid 0.4)$ must be zero for $x < 0$ or $x > 0,4$.

Comment: I believe that I understand the intuition behind it. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to write the equation to match my intuition... It makes perfect sense that if $s = 0.4$, then $x$ must be uniform over $[0, 0.4]$. Or if $s = 1.4$ then $x$ is uniform over $[0.4, 1.0]$. How do I write this intuition into an equation for $P_{X|S}(x|s)$? @DilipSarwate

Comment: I know that the usual steps to calculate $P_{X|S}(x|s)$ would be to divide the joint distribution by the distribution of $s$, or $\frac{P_{X, S}(x, s)}{P_{S}(s)}$. How would I calculate $P_{X, S}(x, s)$ when $s$ is dependent upon $x$?